# Why Auto Complete TextView is not changing the data in dynamic way?

Tags: android, autocomplete, notifydatasetchanged

I have a autocomplete textview with some suggestion. But i want to change the suggestion data when user click a button. 
Here is my code

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
ArrayAdapter adapter;
AutoCompleteTextView view;

Button btn; ArrayList<String>data;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    view=(AutoCompleteTextView)findViewById(R.id.autoCompleteTextView1);
    btn=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
    data=new ArrayList<String>();


    for(int i=0;i<100;i++)
    {
        data.add("Autocomplete"+i);
    }

     adapter = new ArrayAdapter
               (this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,data);
    view.setAdapter(adapter);

    btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                        data.clear();
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Data size"+data.size(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            for(int i=0;i<100;i++)
                        {
                            data.add("NewData"+i);
                        }   
                            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Data size= "+data.size(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }
    });


}
```

It is not working. Previous data are showing. What can i do now?

Comment: it should be `adapter.add("NewData"+i)`

Comment: Thank u very much. Its working. But i have a question. In case of listView when i change the arrayList and call adapter.notifyDatasetChanged method it updates the value. Why it is not working here?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean. What you can do is to look at the implementation of ArrayAdapter on GrepCode. Is not that much

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone is having this issue with AutoCompleteTextView, notifiydatasetchaged() will not work.

You have to update your list data and set adapter again.

```
 'adapter_email =new AutoSuggestAdapter(this,R.layout.spinner_autofill_av_dialouge,Merged);

    av_email.setAdapter(adapter_email);'
```

use both the above lines not just `.setAdapter`.